# How to search with grep in files specified in a text file?

Tags: bash, grep

I want to search with grep for a pattern in a number of files which I specified in a previous step and which are now stored in a text file.

Lets say, in the first step, I used

```
grep -l 'pattern1' *.csv >> ~/filenames.txt
```

to list the filenames of all the csv files which contained pattern1 and save these filenames into filenames.txt

Now I would like to search all of the above files for a second pattern, pattern2.
I'm looking for a command like

```
grep -?? 'pattern2' ~/filenames.txt
```

where -?? tells grep to look for filenames in filenames.txt
I know that

```
grep -f patternfile.txt *.csv
```

Would search all csv files for the patterns defined in patternfile.txt. Is there an analog command for searching all files specified in a file full of filenames?

I'm also happy to hear about alternative solution to my overall problem, e.g. somehow combining step 1 and 2 without the interim filenames.txt but it would also be interesting to know about the analog grep command, if it exists.

To be clear, I am not just looking for files which contain pattern1 and pattern2. I'm interested in all occurrences for pattern2 (and then actually count them) in files in which pattern1 appears at least once.

Comment: Your first command is not going to return the filenames, but the individual lines matching your pattern.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `xargs` for this:

```
xargs -I {} grep -H 'pattern' {} < ~/filenames.txt
```

`grep` will run against filename on each line from `~/filenames` file.

**This will also work with spaces in filenames.**

Comment: Another `xargs` option: `grep "pattern" $(xargs -a filenames.txt)`

Comment: `xargs` is the right tool to use, but as written your command will break with filenames with embedded spaces. The same goes for the variations mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @mklement0: Fair point, my edited `xargs` command will work with spaces in filenames.

Comment: Thanks for updating, but using `-I` is inefficient, because you'll then invoke `grep` individually for each input filename. The solution is to use NUL-separated input combined with `xargs -0` (Linux and BSD/OSX), or `xargs -d '\n'` (Linux only).

Comment: That's right `xargs -d '\n' grep -H 'pattern'  < ~/filenames.txt` is better performing command

Answer (score 2):

To:

- avoid the need for an intermediate file,
- and robustly handle filenames with embedded spaces or globbing pattern characters,

try the following (assumes that you're either on Linux or BSD/OSX):

```
grep -l --null 'pattern1' *.csv | xargs -0 grep 'pattern2'
```

- `-l` tells `grep` to print only the input filename in case of a match
- `--null` separates the filenames with NULs
- `xargs -0` parses the NUL-separated filenames into individual arguments and passes them to the 2nd `grep` command.

On Linux (with *GNU* utilities), you can simplify the command somewhat, assuming you're not worried about filenames with embedded newlines (very rare):

```
grep -l 'pattern1' *.csv | xargs -d '\n' grep 'pattern2'
```

- `-d '\n'` makes `xargs` consider each input line as a whole an individual argument.

Answer (score 1):

or...

```
ack --files-from=filenames.txt 'pattern'
```